# How to deploy a single node elasticsearch cluster in Google Kubernetes engine?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have configured a small instance of google kubernetes cluster with one node. I want to deploy elasticsearch service in this cluster. How do I set up that? I need the necessary steps.

Comment: There are plenty of examples online. Google is your friend: https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-guide-to-deploy-elasticsearch-cluster-on-google-kubernetes-engine-52f67743ee98

Comment: I already tried that it is not working.
I have selected a small GKE cluster(1.6G Ram shared CPU) and one node.

Answer (score 1):

In Google [Cloud Marketplacep](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/) there are different categorie of **elasticsearch** if you want container images:

[image]

You need just to use the gcloud pull command

Elasticsearch 5:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker && docker pull marketplace.gcr.io/google/elasticsearch5:latest
```

Elasticsearch 6:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker && docker pull marketplace.gcr.io/google/elasticsearch6:latest
```

For kubernetes app (like depluing directly to your cluster)

[image][image]

As well you can deply using [HELM](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch) as suggested by @Luiz

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [elasticsearch helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch) and manually tune it's resources limits and requests to fit into one node.